# ethereum solidity: from concatenated hexadecimal strings to uint64[]

Tags: encoding, ethereum, solidity, chainlink

I want my API to return an array of uint64 to my on-chain contract.

I tried 2 response formats for my API:

1. The array of uint64 itself (BN string here, but I need it in true uint64 not strings in my contract):

```
{"data":["629343835796877311","629343835797458943","629343835797471231"]}
```

2. concatenated hexadecimal strings (a new value every 16 chars):

```
{"data":"08bbe0e25e412fff08bbe0e25e4a0fff08bbe0e25e4a3fff"}
```

I discarded using the first approach because having `["629343835796877311","629343835797458943","629343835797471231"]` as bytes is actually difficult to extract. I might be wrong! Maybe there is a base64 approach to encode and decode the data back into solidity data types, maybe?

I will use the second approach bellow.

Chainlink will pass the response as `bytes memory _data`:

```
  function fulfill(bytes32 _requestId, bytes memory _data)
    public
    recordChainlinkFulfillment(_requestId)
  {
      data = string(_data);
  }
```

Those `bytes memory _data` are successfully received and converted to a string (in storage `data`). The string value looks like this

```
08bbe0e25e412fff08bbe0e25e4a0fff08bbe0e25e4a3fff ...
```

In this example each 16 chars represent a uint64 number.
The first one: `08bbe0e25e412fff` is `629343835796877311` for instance.

In solidity, I need to split the string each 16 chars and then convert it into their uint64 value.
I could use the `bytes memory _data` instead of the `string(_data)` if the code would be simpler or consume less gas. I am not sure

Please I need help with this I have been struggling.
Thanks

Comment: You might want to use multi variable response and store your different variables into your array on chain, I think that would be easier and cheaper than converting from bytes: https://docs.chain.link/docs/multi-variable-responses/

Comment: Hi Patrick, I guess with this approach I would be limited to an array of 15 elements because solidity has a 16 parameters limit on function definition. I need more than that. I guess I really need to get that hex string processing to work. 
I was able to have 1 hex string into his uint64 value. I now need to split this concatenated hex strings into chunks of 16 chars each. not easy.

Answer (score 0):

I got this contract working

COMMENTS:

the method `hexBytesToInt` is going to get a string representing hexa value like `ffa0` for instance and return it's decimal value.

the method `getSlice` is just going to slice a string. In my case I have a new hexa value every 16 chars so I need to slice (0,16) than (16,32) etc...

the method `hexStringToIntArray` is managing the increments to slice every 16 chars and call the `hexBytesToInt` to transform the hex string in uint.

If you really want to dig into this solution, you are better off starting by understanding the test cases.

```
pragma solidity >=0.4.22 <0.8.11;

contract Serializer {

    function hexStringToIntArray(string memory s) public pure returns (uint64[] memory) {
        uint size = bytes(s).length / 16;
        uint64[] memory result = new uint64[](size);
        for (uint i = 0; i< size; i++) {
            string memory strSlice = getSlice(i*16, (i+1)*16, s);
            result[i] = hexStringToInt(strSlice);
        }
        return result;
    }

    function getSlice(uint startIndex, uint endIndex, string memory str) public pure returns (string memory) {
        bytes memory strBytes = bytes(str);
        bytes memory result = new bytes(endIndex-startIndex);
        for(uint i = startIndex; i < endIndex; i++) {
            result[i-startIndex] = strBytes[i];
        }
        return string(result);
    }

    function hexBytesToInt(bytes memory ss) public pure returns (uint64){
        uint64 val = 0;
        uint8 a = uint8(97); // a
        uint8 zero = uint8(48); //0
        uint8 nine = uint8(57); //9
        uint8 A = uint8(65); //A
        uint8 F = uint8(70); //F
        uint8 f = uint8(102); //f
        for (uint i=0; i<ss.length; ++i) {
            uint8 byt = uint8(ss[i]);
            if (byt >= zero && byt <= nine) byt = byt - zero;
            else if (byt >= a && byt <= f) byt = byt - a + 10;
            else if (byt >= A && byt <= F) byt = byt - A + 10;
            val = (val << 4) | (byt & 0xF);
        }
        return val;
    }

    function hexStringToInt(string memory s) public pure returns (uint64) {
        bytes memory ss = bytes(s);
        uint64 val = hexBytesToInt(ss);
        return val;
    }
}
```

the tests:

```
const Serializer = artifacts.require("Serializer");
const truffleAssert = require("truffle-assertions");
const fs = require("fs");
const { readLines } = require("./utils.js");
const BN = web3.utils.BN;

contract("Serializer", (accounts) => {
  const [deployerAddress, tokenHolderOneAddress, tokenHolderTwoAddress] = accounts;

  it("hexStringToInt", async () => {
    let s = await Serializer.deployed();
    let result = await s.hexStringToInt.call("08bbe0e25e412fff");
    let expected = new BN("629343835796877311");
    assert.equal(result.toString(10), expected.toString(10));
    result = await s.hexStringToInt.call("08bbe0e25e4a0fff");
    expected = new BN("629343835797458943");
    assert.equal(result.toString(10), expected.toString(10));
    result = await s.hexStringToInt.call("08bbe0e25e4a3fff");
    expected = new BN("629343835797471231");
    assert.equal(result.toString(10), expected.toString(10));
  });
  it("getSlice1", async () => {
    let s = await Serializer.deployed();
    let result = await s.getSlice.call(0, 16, "08bbe0e25e412fff08bbe0e25e4a0fff08bbe0e25e4a3fff");
    let expected = "08bbe0e25e412fff";
    assert.equal(result, expected);
  });
  it("getSlice2", async () => {
    let s = await Serializer.deployed();
    const result = await s.getSlice.call(16, 32, "08bbe0e25e412fff08bbe0e25e4a0fff08bbe0e25e4a3fff");
    const expected = "08bbe0e25e4a0fff";
    assert.equal(result, expected);
  });
  it("getSlice3", async () => {
    let s = await Serializer.deployed();
    const result = await s.getSlice.call(32, 48, "08bbe0e25e412fff08bbe0e25e4a0fff08bbe0e25e4a3fff");
    const expected = "08bbe0e25e4a3fff";
    assert.equal(result, expected);
  });
  it("hexStringToIntArray", async () => {
    let s = await Serializer.deployed();
    let result = await s.hexStringToIntArray.call("08bbe0e25e412fff08bbe0e25e4a0fff08bbe0e25e4a3fff");
    console.log(result);
    let expected = [
      new BN("629343835796877311").toString(),
      new BN("629343835797458943").toString(),
      new BN("629343835797471231").toString(),
    ];
    const resultS = result.map((x) => x.toString());
    assert.deepEqual(resultS, expected);
  });
});
```

Comment: I don't know what I am doing with the `memory` keyword. Could this code be optimised?

Comment: Could you please put the minimized solution at the top? In it's current state it's really hard for others to understand your solution.

Comment: I added some comments, I hope it helps. I am not sure if this is really going to be useful as chainlink as been around for a long time and I am the only one doing such things. I am potentially doing something wrong here. The gas of this code is pretty high for instance